# Positional index of list elements using Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm looking to create a positional_index function that takes in two or more lists as argument and should return the doc_id and the position of the word that occurs in various lists.

ex:

```
index = create_positional_index([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']])
index['a']
[[0, 0, 2], [1, 0]]
index['b']
[[0, 1]]
index['c']
[[1, 1]]
```

Here the first '0' represents the doc_id followed by the positions at which 'a' appears in document 0. since 'a' appears in both the documents we've got two lists. 'b' appears only in document 0 and 'c' appears only in document 1..

can anyone help me write this function ?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: i dont have any clue to do this

Comment: Which part exactly? How to write a function? Finding indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using dict's for doc_id.

EDIT:  Changed function to OPs output format.

```
class create_positional_index():
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __getitem__(self, elm):
        return [[doc_id] + [pos for pos, key  in enumerate(sub_lst) if key==elm] for doc_id, sub_lst in enumerate(self.lst) if elm in sub_lst]

index = create_positional_index([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']])
print index['a']
print index['b']
print index['c']

def create_positional_index2(lst, elm):
    return [[doc_id] + [pos for pos, key  in enumerate(sub_lst) if key==elm] for doc_id, sub_lst in enumerate(lst) if elm in sub_lst]

print create_positional_index2([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']], 'a')
print create_positional_index2([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']], 'b')
print create_positional_index2([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']], 'c')
```

Comment: can you explain your code plz. I'm a newbie to python so im finding it hard to understand..

Comment: can you edit your function to display the output in the way how i mentioned it above ?

Comment: @Wolf I have updated the function to your desired output.  Could you explain what part of the function you do not understand?

Comment: why do you use class definition ? I want this to be defined as a function so that i can call it from the main program..

Comment: can you explain the def init and getitem part for me ?

Comment: you must use a class in order to get the desired output using the index['a'] call.  A simple function does not support indexing (that is index['a'] will cause an error).  you can us a simple function as desired, but you will lose the index['a'] functionality (see post).

Comment: @wolf see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html# and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html for a desciriotpino on how __init__ and __getitem__ work

Comment: @wolf please accept the answer if you find it useful

Comment: yes i understood the init and getitem portion..can you explain what you've done in the return part ? i'm getting confused there..can you give a clear explanation plz ..sorry for the trouble again

Comment: The return part of __getItem__ and create_positional_index2 use list comprehensions to give your desired output.  Explaining exactly how it works is outside the scope of a comment.  I have provided resource which should give you a good start on how they work:  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sample_list = [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c']]
>>> def find_index(s_list) :
...     for elem in set(chain(*s_list)) :
...        yield {elem:[[i]+[t for t,k in enumerate(j) if k==elem] for i,j in enumerate(s_list)]}
... 
>>> list(find_index(sample_list)
... )
[{'a': [[0, 0, 2], [1, 0]]}, {'c': [[0], [1, 1]]}, {'b': [[0, 1], [1]]}]
```

All stuff that you need here is using `enumerate` within two list comprehension . note that `set(chain(*s_list))` create a set of unique elements of all your sub_lists .

Comment: what does 'elem' refer to in your function ?

Comment: @Wolf its the specific element that you want to search for its index

Comment: can you suggest a function that takes only the list as the input argument plz ?

Comment: your output gives the positional index of all words. can you specify changes to your code in such a way that when i call index['a'] i should get only the positional index of ['a'] ?? as i've shown in my desired output section above..

Comment: @Wolf exactly you can do it with result . and if you found this answer helpful you can tell this to community with voting and accepting the answer !

Comment: can you edit your function to produce output as ive shown above ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it fairly difficult to understand your question. However in spite of of that and after looking at the other answers along with your comments, I think the following would be a good way to accomplish want your goal. It defines a subclass of `dict` to hold the index, so you can also use regular dictionary methods such as `keys()`, `items()`, or `update` on any instances created if you want.

```
from itertools import chain

class PositionalIndex(dict):
    def __init__(self, *lists):
        self.update(
            (doc_id, [[i]+[j for j, k in enumerate(sublist) if k == doc_id]
                        for i, sublist in enumerate(lists)])
                            for doc_id in set(chain.from_iterable(lists)))

index = PositionalIndex(['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'c'])

for doc_id in sorted(index):
    print('index[{!r}] --> {}'.format(doc_id, index[doc_id]))
```

Output:

```
index['a'] --> [[0, 0, 2], [1, 0]]
index['b'] --> [[0, 1], [1]]
index['c'] --> [[0], [1, 1]]
```